# What is the purpose of stepfun in ecdf()?

Tags: r

```
R> ecdf
function (x)
{
    x <- sort(x)
    n <- length(x)
    if (n < 1)
        stop("'x' must have 1 or more non-missing values")
    vals <- unique(x)
    rval <- approxfun(vals, cumsum(tabulate(match(x, vals)))/n,
        method = "constant", yleft = 0, yright = 1, f = 0, ties = "ordered")
    class(rval) <- c("ecdf", "stepfun", class(rval))
    assign("nobs", n, envir = environment(rval))
    attr(rval, "call") <- sys.call()
    rval
}
```

The above is the code of ecdf(). I see that the return value is assigned with class `stepfun`. I don't understand what it is for. Given `approxfun()` does linear interpolation, why is stepfun needed? What is the purpose of adding `stepfun` to the class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the call to `approxfun()` in `ecdf()`, the `method` is `"constant"`, which means it isn't doing linear interpolation, it's generating a step function.

To find out what the class on the result affects, you can use the `methods()` function:

```r
methods(class="stepfun")
#> [1] knots   lines   plot    print   summary
#> see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1.9000)</sup>

So potentially if you call any of the `knots()`, `lines()`, `plot()`, `print()` or `summary()` functions on the result you'll get behaviour tailored to step functions.  However, the class of the result is computed as `c("ecdf", "stepfun", class(rval))`, so there might be `"ecdf"` methods that override the `"stepfun"` methods:

```r
methods(class="ecdf")
#> [1] plot     print    quantile summary 
#> see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1.9000)</sup>

Yes, the `plot()`, `print()` and `summary()` functions will call the `"ecdf"` methods in preference to the `"stepfun"` methods.  That still leaves `knots()` and `lines()`, and conceivably the others could call `NextMethod()` to get to the `"stepfun"` methods.

One clarification:  the `method` argument to `approxfun()` is just the name of an argument; in the discussion above, "methods" was used to refer to one of the ways R does object oriented programming, using methods and classes.